# how to add 1 day to given date in python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to add one day to the date given as argument for a python script

I mean a date will be passed as follows while calling the script *python  -d mm/dd/yyyy*
code:

```
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='XYZ')
 parser.add_argument("-d","--date",required=True,dest="help", help="help")
```

I want to add one day to given day
I'm trying this :

```
check_date = args.date
check_pass_date =datetime.check_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

this check_pass_date I later want to use as argument for function
I'm getting following error for this:
`type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'check_date'`

Is this reg the importing of module or what? How can I add one day to given date?

Comment: typo with `datetime.check_date`? try removing `datetime.` from `datetime.check_date`.

Comment: It is unclear how `args.date` is created, please add piece of code to show how it is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert the current time in seconds to a `date` object, and format it to a string very conveniently using `date.strftime(format)`:

```py
import time
from datetime import date

def get_future_date(days: int) -> str:
    futureday = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(time.time() + (86400 * days))
    return futureday.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

print(get_future_date(1))
```

Here we take the current time using `time.time()`, and add x days to that time by multiplying the amount of days passed to the function by the amount of seconds in a day (86400)